# Unable to connect to CitusData - SQLSTATE[08006] error

Tags: docker, citus

I am getting an issue with CitusData docker version on MAC.

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
```

List of docker containers below:

```
ba187040a5ca        citusdata/citus:8.2.2                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)   5432/tcp                                   citus_worker_1
3105ddb06049        citusdata/membership-manager:0.2.0   "python -u ./manager…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)                                              citus_manager
2cbd2b2bad49        citusdata/citus:8.2.2                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)   0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp                     citus_master
```

docker-compose.yml - https://docs.citusdata.com/en/stable/installation/single_machine_docker.html#post-install
    version: '2.1'

```
services:
  master:
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME:-citus}_master"
    image: 'citusdata/citus:8.2.2'
    ports: ["${MASTER_EXTERNAL_PORT:-5432}:5432"]
    labels: ['com.citusdata.role=Master']
  worker:
    image: 'citusdata/citus:8.2.2'
    labels: ['com.citusdata.role=Worker']
    depends_on: { manager: { condition: service_healthy } }
  manager:
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME:-citus}_manager"
    image: 'citusdata/membership-manager:0.2.0'
    volumes: ['/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock']
    depends_on: { master: { condition: service_healthy } }
```

Comment: Please provide more info like `Dockerfile` or `docker-compse` file and the way ran the container

Comment: Edited the question with file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5433 port seems to be the problem in master container. `0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp`. PostgreSQL uses 5432 port by default, and this seems to be the reason why the connection is refused.

Did you change the default port mapping in `docker-compose.yml`? Maybe you set `MASTER_EXTERNAL_PORT=5433` and forgot to use that when trying to reach citus database.

If you wish to continue using `5433` port, you can use `psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 5433` to connect to the database.